# Run SQL script inside Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a scripted database SQL file that I need to execute *inside* Visual Studio to create a new database. I am so far unable to locate any function that allows me to do this.

Comment: What do you mean "execute inside visual studio" - that doesn't really mean anything in terms of running an SQL script

Answer (score 10):

Go to server explorer in VS, right click on server and select run query.

Do you mind telling us why it has to be run inside VS?

In addition, the database projects offers a lot of features that are worth looking at:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31764 //old article but still worth reading.

http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/standards/BetterSoftwareSuggestions/Images/VisualStudio_DataDude_SchemaCompare.gif

http://www.emadibrahim.com/2008/07/10/database-schema-compare-upgrade/

Answer (score 1):

There is a green arrow of play on the upper left corner of the window query. And down the tabs of the names of open files in VS. Just click to play and ready.